# reduce length of native base input line

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, react-native, native-base

I am using this in my app:

```
<Item fixedLabel>
              <Input style={{ width: 0.5 }}/>
            </Item>
```

the length of the the fixedLabel line extends to the whole screen. How can I reduce its size? I have already tried using `width`and `paddingLeft/right`, but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it inside a div and then add style to that div

```
<div className='cusmtomClass'>
  <Item fixedLabel>
    <Input style={{ width: 0.5 }}/>
  </Item>
</div>
```